# NoSuchElementException on heroku but works on localhost

Tags: java, selenium, heroku, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have some oddsportal parsing app, that works perfectly on localhost, but when I upload it to heroku, it can't find an element by xpath.
It goes to the page with `driver.get("url")`(chrome and chromedriver are installed), i can see in logs currentUrl, but then it just doesn't see elements

I've tried `Thread.sleep(n)` where n was even 120 seconds, have tried 
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);` Nothing helps

Snippet of code:

```
options.setBinary("/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/results/#soccer");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@href='/soccer/austria/tipico-bundesliga/results/']")));
element.click();
```

Page opens when i use it on localhost, but

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='/basketball/usa/nba/results/']"}
```

in logs on heroku

Answer (score 1):

As per *best practices*, when your *usecase* is to invoke a `click()` on any element, once the page loads just after `driver.get()` instead of `presenceOfElementLocated()` you need to use the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as **`elementToBeClickable()`** as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='/soccer/austria/tipico-bundesliga/results/']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a few steps that might solve this issue:
1. Check you are on the right page.
2. Check the page is fully loaded by using

```
private void WaitUntilDocumentIsReady(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeout);            

    // Check if document is ready
    Func<IWebDriver, bool> readyCondition = webDriver => js.
        .ExecuteScript("return (document.readyState == 'complete' && jQuery.active == 0)");
    wait.Until(readyCondition);
}
```

3. Try Javascript click `js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: got your point and made a method in java, but still the same error ( I just don't understand why it's working on localhost, but on heroku it gets correct url of page but doesn't see elements

Comment: It could be rezolution issue try to maximize the window